Is it possible to host a Blazor WebAssembly app inside business central control add-in?
Is it possible to host a Blazor WebAssembly app inside a business central control add-in?
To clarify this better, I do not want the Blazor app to be hosted on a server and then be loaded in the control add-in, I want to host it in the control add-in.

you can use the iFrame but it's not a better approach and is effective.

You are not taking into account that the question is related to business central, your answer is not relevant at all in this situation.

I guess technically the answer is yes, but I wouldn't recommend doing it.
I have seen a hack where someone included WebAssembly in the Control Add-in by renaming the assemblies to jpeg files.
This will result in the compiler packaging the files with the app meaning they would be available for usage once the app is published.
Again I would consider this extremely experimental and not recommended for production environments.
It is an exploit for how the compiler packages resources at the moment which might be subject to change.

I set blazor.webassembly.js as a StartupScript in the control add-in and included dotnet.js in Scripts and I am getting this exception: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module in dotnet.js. Could there be a workaround to this, or should I just give up on trying, as this is not recommended as you said. The problem is I have not been able to find anything on the web about this topic...

Even if there is a workaround it would be by chance not because it was intended for you to do so. Therefore I wouldn't use it in production code.
